# How many total gifts in the twelve days of christmas if we extend 12 to any number?

Tags: algorithm

I got this question today in an interview:  write a function to calculate the total number of gifts received for any day in the 12 days of christmas song.  I wrote a simple function using a for() loop in c#'ish code that worked.  Then the interviewer asked me to extend it to any number of days.  The conversation then turned to how to optimize the loop.  Apparently there's a cool math trick that will do this within the limits of whatever your integer is.   Anyone know what it is and what it's called?  Any language is ok and a reference to the algorithm would be fabuloso.

Answers that use recursion are NOT what I'm looking for.

EDIT: Answer for day 2 is 4 gifts total, not 3 since I will have 2 Trees (1 from today, 1 from yesterday) and 2 partridges.  On day 12 I'll have received a total of 364.  I want the formula that lets me input 12 and get 364.

Comment: math "trick"? It's not a trick, it's algebra.  On day `n`, you get `g(n) = 1 + 2 + ... + n` gifts.  So in `N` days, you get a total of `T(N) = g(1) + g(2) + ... + g(N)` objects.

Comment: You have to know N to code this function.

Comment: Of course.  Isn't this the point?  To know the number of gifts in `N` days, you need to know `N`.

Comment: You have to know the song to code this function.

Comment: Wow.  Who knew it would become famous over Christmas this year.  Thanks for all the interest (no pun intended)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- On the first day, you get 1.
- On the second day, you get 1 + 2.
- On the third day, you get 1 + 2 + 3.
- ...
- On `n`th day, you get 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + `n`.

The sum `1 + 2 + ... + n` is `n(n+1)/2`.  So the total number, `T(N)` is the sum of `n(n+1)/2` for `n` in `1..N`, where `N` is the number of days.

Now, `n(n+1)/2 = n^2 / 2 + n / 2`, and sum of `n^2` for `n` in `1..N` is `N(N+1)(2N+1)/6`, so you get:

```
T(N) = N(N+1)(2N+1)/12 + N(N+1)/4
     = N(N^2 + 3N + 2) / 6
```

No loops.  No recursion.

Comment: Easy once you see it. Thanks.  And I REALLY love SO.  It's my new favorite site.

Answer (score 5):

The $P$-th type of present (where the $1$st is partridges, the $2$nd is turtle doves, etc.) comes in quantities of `$P = \sum_{X = 1}^{P} 1$`.

On day $D$, you receive presents of type $1$ through $D$, for a total of `$\sum_{P = 1}^{D} \sum_{X = 1}^{P}` 1$ many presents on that day.

And so, if the days run from $1$ through $N$ (canonically, $N$ is 12, but our interest now is in allowing it to vary), you receive overall `$\sum_{D = 1}^{N} \sum_{P = 1}^{D} \sum_{X = 1}^{P} 1$`.

This counts the number of non-decreasing triples `$1 \leq X \leq P \leq D \leq N$.`

This is the same as the number of increasing triples `$1 \leq X < P + 1 < D + 2 \leq N + 2$.`

So the answer is `$\binom{N + 2}{3} = \frac{(N + 2)(N + 1)N}{6}$.`

Comment: Oh, I thought this site supported LaTeX in the same way as MathOverflow/math.stackexchange/etc., but I see I was mistaken...

Comment: You can use the ` marks to surround something in order to set something apart, but yes, unfortunately LaTeX is not currently part of the SO.

Answer (score 1):

On the *n* th day, we get `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n` gifts.

Or ... `(1 + n) + (2 + n-1) + ...`

In other words, `(n + 1) * n/2`.

Comment: The question asks for total gifts after N days, not the gifts on the nth day.

Comment: That's the number of gifts received on day N itself, not the number of gifts received cumulatively up to day N.

Comment: @Jeff Meatball Yang - +1 for 1st person to understand the question.  Everyone upvoting doesn't get it.

Comment: @No Refunds No Returns: Maybe it's not that noone understands the question. Maybe you don't understand the answer or the question is wrong :) Seriously though, people are not giving the full answer, although you should be able to extrapolate from the partial answer. What you actually have is a geometric series where each term happens to be an arithmetic series.

Answer (score -1):

You receive 364 gifts.

1
2+1=3
3+2+1=6
4+3+2+1=10
5+4+3+2+1=15
6+5+4+3+2+1=21
7+6+5+4+3=2+1=28
8+7+6+5+4+3+2+=36
9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1=45
10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1=55
11+10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1=66
12+11+10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1=78

If you add all of them up you’ll get 364.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question.